# cannot retrieve storage url of an object in firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am a beginner in javascript as well as react.when i want to submit my file in storage and store its storageURL in database.But due to asynchronous nature of javascript before the submission of file it is retrieving the storageurl and hence showing "object not found".Though the file is getting saved in storage.

```
handleSave=()=>{
let bucketName="images"
let file=this.state.files[0]
var a=bucketName+"/"+file.name;
let storageRef=fire.storage().ref(a)
let uploadTask=storageRef.put(file)

var database = firebase.database();
uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
()=>{

//let downloadURL=uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
})
uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then( 
(downloadURL)=> { 
var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('users').push().key;

   
    var updates = {};
    updates['/users/' + localStorage.getItem('key')+"-"+newPostKey] = downloadURL;
    
    
    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
    }).catch((error)=>{console.log("error")
    this.setState({error})
})   
    this.setState({ progress:"uploaded successfully" });
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're waiting for the upload to fully complete before requesting the download URL.

Comment: Sir how can i make sure that upload is complete

Answer (score 0):

I Figured out the problem.The DownloadUrl from snapshot was asked for before the complete uploade of the file.
This works now->

```
     handleSave=()=>{
     this.setState({ progress:"uploading please wait......" });

     let bucketName="images"
     let file=this.state.files[0]
     var a=bucketName+"/"+file.name;
     let storageRef=firebase.storage().ref(a)
     let uploadTask=storageRef.put(file)

     var database = firebase.database();

     uploadTask.then((snapshot)=>{
     const progress = Math.round(
     (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
      );
     this.setState({ progress:(progress+" % uploaded" )});


      snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then( 
     (downloadURL)=> { 
      var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('users').push().key;

   
      var updates = {};
     updates['/users/'+localStorage.getItem('key')+"--"+newPostKey] = 
     downloadURL;
    
    
    return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
    }).catch((error)=>{console.log(error)
    this.setState({error})
})  

})}
```